# Is it possible to reference a class instance without using the variable it's stored in?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, variables

```
class Dog:
  def __init__(self, ap1)
    self.name = ap1
    self.tricks = []
  def.addTrick(self, ap1)
    self.tricks.append(ap1)
```

So above I have a class meant to spawn instances of dogs.

```
curDog=Dog("Seymour")
curDog.addTrick("Wait Forever")
print("curDog is " + curDog.name)
print(curDog.name + " knows " + str(curDog.tricks))
print("")

curDog=Dog("Brian")
curDog.addTrick("Psuedo Intellectual Debate")
print("curDog is " + curDog.name)
print(curDog.name + " knows " + str(curDog.tricks))
print("")
```

And above here I have two instances, `Dog('Seymour')` and `Dog('Brian')`, occupying the same variable `curDog`(current dog), serially. The output looks like this:

```
>>> main()
curDog is Seymour
Seymour knows ['Wait Forever']

curDog is Brian
Brian knows ['Pseudo Intellectual Debate']

>>>
```

Obviously I realize that once curDog is used to store Brian that it will no longer reference Seymour. But at this point I wonder what has happened to Seymour. Is he still out in there in the environment ether, merely disconnected from the variable link? Or is he totally annihilated to make room for Brian?

If the former, how can I access him and his trick list?

More to the original point of the post, is it possible to reference Brian without using `curDog`? I have tried the likes of `print("Brian".tricks)` and `print(Dog('Brian').tricks)`, but I wasn't much surprised when they didn't work.

Is there a way to do this? Is there a better way to understand class instances that could help me answer this myself?

Comment: Once there are no remaining references to an object, it's freed up for garbage collection - at some indeterminate point in the future, it will be overwritten in memory with something else. If you need to keep access to multiple instances, put them in a dictionary or list.

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is "garbage collection". There has been a lot written about it. For example: http://arctrix.com/nas/python/gc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by adding some code to tell you when Seymour gets garbage collected.

```
class Dog:
  # ...
  def __del__(self):
    print('*** deleting {} ***'.format(self.name))
```

Running the code with this addition shows you exactly what happens:

```
curDog is Seymour
Seymour knows ['Wait Forever']

*** deleting Seymour ***
curDog is Brian
Brian knows ['Psuedo Intellectual Debate']

*** deleting Brian ***
```

It's worth noting that there is no guarantee the program has to behave this way. The Python interpreter has the option of waiting to remove Seymour until some later point - perhaps when the program ends, or when it needs memory, or so on. So don't write Python programs that rely on objects being garbage-collected right away. But in practice, there is no advantage in waiting, so the interpreter deletes objects as soon as they are no longer referenced.

There can, of course, be multiple references to an object - that is, the same object can be stored in multiple variables. You could make a new variable `curDog2` and store Seymour in that, then when you reassign `curDog` to Brian, Seymour will still be referenced by `curDog2`, which gives the interpreter a reason not to garbage-collect it. Objects only disappear in this way when there are *no* references to them remaining. (Not counting weak references, but that's a whole other story.)

However, the interpreter does not create any references of its own to your custom objects. So there is no way to access an object except by going through some variable or something in which you've stored it.

Comment: A perfect answer. Thank you.